# How to call image from media folder?

Tags: magento-1.9, media

To call the image from my `media/img` folder & display it in my list page I have used the below code:

```
 <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/img/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

Now I want to call the image from my `media/wysiwyg` folder.

Is there any other way to call image from there apart from above mentioned code? Someone guide me please.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

**Updated**

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/wysiwyg/ ".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

Comment: I tried that. The images are getting broken.

Comment: if your image is inside **wysiwyg** then you have to place a wysiwyg in place of img please check the updated answer.

Comment: Is there any other way to call the image. By means of creating variable?

Comment: what do you mean creating variable please explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl('media').trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

Comment: The images are getting broken.

Comment: just check images exists at that path

Comment: Ya the images are inside `wysiwyg` of media.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/img/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

With:

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it from

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/img/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by original? I just need to call the image inside my `media/wysiwyg` folder for the attribute craeted.

Comment: I have updated the anser plz check

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for media url :

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

This will return path to media directory, like : `http://magento.demo/media/`

Now you can append some **STATIC** things, like `/img/` OR `/wysiwyg/` as per your requirement (**where the image resides**).

**Final step:**
Now append the name of your image file,

if image name is like `abc.png` then use :

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/img/".trim($value)."'/>"; ?>
```

if image name is like `abc` then use :

```
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/img/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
```

**Note:** Replace `/img/` as per your requirement